# IOS Tab Bar Item Popup Submenu

Tags: ios, popup

Good Day,

i am looking for a solution of how to make the UITabbar item can popup a submenu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What part are you having trouble with?  It seem pretty simple.  Make custom view controller with a tabBar (don't use UITabBarController), for most tab bar items show the correct viewController (ie add as a childViewController), but for more show a popup (a different childViewController).  Remember than when the more popup is dismissed to reselect the current tab on the tabbar.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. i am tried this solution before but when i use tabBar but the tabBar item can't link to the view controller.. i am sorry for ask this question because i just start learning ios..